# insert entire same row beneath when condition was met

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on the below code to insert same entire row below/beneath original one. I had a hard time fulfilling the requirement because I am just new to making macros.

I already tried searching but not able to code correctly. It is working to insert an empty row. But what I need is to insert the row that met the condition. Below is the screenshot/code for my macro.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim rFound As Range, c As Range
Dim myVals
Dim i As Long

myVals = Array("LB") '<- starts with 51, VE etc
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Range("F1", Range("F" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
    For i = 0 To UBound(myVals)
        .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:=myVals(i)
        On Error Resume Next
        Set rFound = .Offset(2).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) _
            .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
        On Error GoTo 0
        .AutoFilter
        If Not rFound Is Nothing Then
            For Each c In rFound
                Rows(c.Row + 1).Insert
                c.Offset(1, -1).Value = ActiveCell.Value
            Next c
        End If
    Next i
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Test()

    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngData As Range
    Dim rngArea As Range
    Dim rngFiltered As Range
    Dim cell As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1").CurrentRegion
    'Exclude header
    With rng
        Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1)
    End With
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=6, Criteria1:="LB"
    Set rngFiltered = rngData.Columns("F:F").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    rng.AutoFilter Field:=6
    For Each rngArea In rngFiltered.Areas
        For Each cell In rngArea
            '// When inserting a row,
            '// iteration variable "cell" is adjusted accordingly.
            Rows(cell.Row + 1).Insert
            Rows(cell.Row).Copy Rows(cell.Row + 1)
        Next
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Johnyl thanks for sharing this.  I got some issue in  Set rngData = .Offset(1).Resize(.Rows.Count - 1) . the error is 1004 "Application-defined or Object-defined error". I am doing my testing using Active X control command button on my spreadsheet. are you familiar about that? Thank you.

Comment: @sayjon I see that your range starts from A1 cell, so Range("A1").CurrentRegion will work for you. rngData is for excluding header. I don't know why this error happens for you. I can tell you only by looking at actual workbook.

Comment: Now I got it. But there's another issue. At the first click execution it's working well. but at the second click of my button it will run continuously and hang. maybe there's a code missing to stop the last execution. I just want to duplicate the entire rows once to have two rows with the same data or values. Thank you for your help..

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code I just used . Thank you!

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Dim x As Long

    For x = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge To 1 Step -1

        If Cells(x, "F") = "LB" Then
        Cells(x, "F") = "ComP"
        Cells(x + 1, "F").EntireRow.Insert
        Cells(x, "F").EntireRow.Copy Cells(x + 1, "F").EntireRow

        End if
    Next x

End Sub
```